# iOS: How to show default phone detected action sheet

Tags: ios, uitextview, system

If UITextView setup to detect phone numbers, it will show popup action sheet list from bottom with actions like sms or call. (iOS 7)

is it possible to show this sheet in other situations/programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. You should see the `UIActivityViewController` class.

Comment: please, more details. is there any pattern / template method for that phone detected activity view controller?

Comment: No, iOS handle it. Can you explain in which case you want to use it?

Comment: I want to show this action sheet when user tap on button "Connect to operator"

Comment: You can show this action sheet by passing some related data. When you pass text, iOS shows you apps which handle it eq. Mail, SMS, Twitter...
If you would show phone apps, you should pass phone number or any data in relation to phone apps.